# Importing packages from different folders

Tags: haxe

For a variety of reasons, I have the folder structure of my project set up like this: There is a root folder, which holds my Project.xml file and all of that stuff, and then I have two separate folders, which both contain source code in them.

In my project.xml file, I specify that both of those folders contain source files, and I can run code from either folder no problem. However, I run into weirdness when trying to import packages between the two folders.

Classes in folder 1 are able to import packages from folder 2 and use them. However, classes in folder 2 are not able to import packages from folder 1, and classes in folder 1 can't import other packages within folder 1. They simply wont recognize that the package exists.

I have no idea what's going on here, do you guys have any idea how to import packages between folders like this?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, sorry, never mind, I figured it out. I didn't realize this, but the package names MUST match the folders that they are placed in, AND the names of those folders MUST start with a lowercase letter. I find that very odd, but whatever, it works now.

Comment: This kind of conventions is herited from the Java philosophy for example. Where between each layer of your application (package, classes, methods, variables, etc.) you switch from camelCase to CamelCase convention.

Like that, you can easily figure out where your are in your project hierarchie.

I hope, it's clarify a little bit.